# Synchronise user accounts over multiple systems

Tags: login, multiple-users

In my office I have 10 computers and all of them run Ubuntu. I have 20 employees each with their own login. Is it possible to set things up so that every employee can log in on any of the computers and access their own desktop (passwords, Gmail login, etc)?

For example, one day User1 is using computer1 and has their own desktop with icons and favorites etc. The next day computer1 is busy so User1 logs in on computer2 and will there find everything the same as it was yesterday on computer1.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

OpenLDAP could be used to have the same login credentials for multiple users across multiple boxes. Then do what @Rinzwind suggested and mount /home from a NAS.

Comment: I always forget about LDAP :P +1

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but with a lot of trouble. It would be a lot easier to just assign a system to a user.

A possible manual method would be to get a NAS and add it to your network.

Set up all systems to have all users (so all can log in onto any desktop). Set /home/ up to point to the NAS so anyone that logs into the system sees that as their /home/. Can be done by editing `~.config/user-dirs.dirs`. Has a benefit that files stay at the office (ie. on the NAS).

There is a tool called [puppet](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/managing-linux-using-puppet) but that might be overkill for what you want. It lets you service computers in your network (you have added benefit that you can update your system from that system). Puppet lets you set up your system as the puppetmaster (ie. a host) where you can sync files with the puppets (ie. clients).